# External table in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, external

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks ( 
exchange STRING, symbol STRING, ymd STRING, price_open FLOAT, price_high FLOAT, 
price_low FLOAT, price_close FLOAT, volume INT, price_adj_close FLOAT) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/data/stocks';
```

I do not see any folder stocks in HDFS. Where it will be created?

Answer (score 1):

EXTERNAL TABLE will point to the location you specified.
here it is /data/stocks.
check what this command is returning hadoop fs -ls /data/stocks